# Create WindowsIdentity using just a domain and username

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-identity

I am building a site that gets user information using the WindowsIdentity of the current user.  The main info I get from this is the ssid.

I do this for the current users as follows

```
IntPtr logonToken = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token;
WindowsIdentity windowsId = new WindowsIdentity(logonToken);
string ssid = windowsId.User.ToString();
```

What I need to do now, and am failing at, is getting the ssid for any arbitrary username that exists on the domain.

I tried WindowsIdentity(string), but that gave me a SecurityException

> The name provided is not a properly formed account name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you formatting the principal? Generally they take the form of `user@domain.ext`, so if your AD provides principal resolution on say `example.com`, a user principal name (UPN) may look like: `joe.bloggs@example.com`.  The `WindowsIdentity(string)` constructor accepts a UPN, not an older format username `EXAMPLE\joe.bloggs`

Comment: oh ok.. I'll give that a go and see what happens.. Thanks

Comment: I had a bit of trouble, since my UPN wasn't joe.bloggs@example.com
I used my DirectorySearcher to query the userPrincipalName, which was a slight variation of the @example.com.. works a charm.. Thanks

Comment: I have only a string like "DOMAIN\username", how can I get WindowsPrincipal ?

Comment: Having DOMAIN\Username, try turning it around to Username@DOMAIN.
If you know the target domain(s), you can also keep a keyvalue list with DOMAIN + DOMAIN.ext, so that you create a proper UPN: Username@DOMAIN.ext.

The last should work, unsure on just username@domain. And if neither DOMAIN\Username or Username@DOMAIN.ext works, then there is something else being the issue. Maybe domain is inaccessible.