# Get Active Directory User Context from AD username string - use with IsInRole()

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Using C#, is it possible to create an IPrincipal User from a string username? I think my question is as simple at that :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
WindowsPrincipal pFoo = new WindowsPrincipal(new WindowsIdentity("domain\user"));
```

Comment: I think that needs escaped like "domain\\user", but that returns "The name provided is not a properly formed account name."

Comment: Nice, it's just NT username. So WindowsPrincipal pFoo = new WindowsPrincipal(new WindowsIdentity("user")); works!

Comment: @farina [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933643/create-windowsidentity-using-just-a-domain-and-username) is the solution to the exception you are getting